# Trying to sumif items greater than x using Lambda in a groupby function in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of Credit Card Transactions and want to create a groupby table in python to count AND sum the transaction amounts greater than 10k, 5k and 1k.  Here is my code:

```
test = df.groupby('Customer Name').agg(
    Credit_Card_Trans = pd.NamedAgg('USD Amount', 'sum'),
    Avg = pd.NamedAgg('USD Amount', 'mean'),
    No = pd.NamedAgg('USD Amount', 'count'),
    k100 = pd.NamedAgg('USD Amount', lambda x: (x>100000).sum()),
    k10 = pd.NamedAgg('USD Amount', lambda x: (x>10000).sum()),
    k5 = pd.NamedAgg('USD Amount', lambda x: (x>5000).sum()),
    k1 = pd.NamedAgg('USD Amount', lambda x: (x>1000).sum())
                     ).sort_values(by = 'Credit_Card_Trans', ascending = False)
print (test)
```

Here is my output:
Customer Name        Credit_Card_Trans   Avg   No  .. k10  k5   k1
abc company           4,500,000         15,000 22      4   12   19

How can I get this code to Sum the dollar values AND count the values.  The sum() seems to be counting and I don't understand why.

Comment: I think you're misusing the function argument.  It should be a function such that if passed the entire list of values, it returns the value you want.  So `lambda x: sum(y for y in x if y > 1000)`

Comment: Brilliant...that worked...many thanks.